# Regular expression replaces invalid words

Tags: regex

I have this sentence and i use regular expressions to replace the word `"merda"` or `"merdas"` with `---`

```
"merda vamerda e mais mmmerda? a merdaaa lol merda, namerda m e r d a mesmo merda"
```

This is the regular expression im using:

```
m{1,}e{1,}r{1,}d{1,}a{1,}s{1,}|m{1,}e{1,}r{1,}d{1,}a{1,}
```

and this is the result:

```
"--- va --- e mais --- ? a --- lol --- , na --- m e r d a mesmo ---"
```

3 errors here, `vamerda` and `namerda` should not be replaced, and it didnt replace `m e r d a`.

Can you help me please?

Comment: That's a clbuttic problem, right there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

how about :

```
/\bm+\s*e+\s*r+\s*d+\s*a+\s*s*\b/
```

**explanation:**

```
\b       : word boundary
m+       : matches 1 or more m
\s*      : matches 0 or more spaces
...   same explanation for other letters (e,r,d,a)
s*       : matches 0 or more s
\b       : word boundary
```

This will match all expected combinations in the given example.

*Edit*

According to your comment, you can modify the regex by exchanging each `\s*` with `[\s_]*` like :

```
\bm+[\s_]*e+[\s_]*  and so on ...
```

or even with:

```
\bm+[^a-z]* ...
```

Comment: If you dont want to match the trailing space you could do `/\bm+\s*e+\s*r+\s*d+\s*a+(?:\s*s)*\b/`

Comment: This is absolutely perfect! Worked on other variations i tried as well. As you might have guessed this is for a profanity filter I'm implementing. I dont mean to ask for more than i should but can it be modified so that it catches m e r d a or m_e_r_d_a, you know what i mean? that if between each character is not a letter instead of just spaces?  THANKS a lot M42 for the quick reply

Comment: Perfect, thanks and have a great day. Thank you for all the other replies as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting your regular expression in [Rubular](http://rubular.com/)

It will give you real-time match results, as you modify your regex.

Here's a link to your expression in Rubular [permalink](http://rubular.com/r/3Z2f9DkcuB)

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
/\Amerda\s+|\smerda,|\smerda\z|\s+merdas\s+|m\se\sr\sd\sa\s/
```

Comment: this will not match `mmmerda` as expected.

Comment: but I thought you need to replace only "merda" and "merdas" - "mmmerdas" is not "merda" right?

Comment: I don't need anything, I'm not the OP, but in the given example, the OP explicitly wants to match `mmmerda`.

Comment: hope this will help: /\A(m)+erda\s+|\s(m)+erda,|\s(m)+erda\z|\s+(m)+erda\W|\s+(m)+erdas\s+|(m)+\se\sr\sd\sa\s/